# How to disable logging during the run of database migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running rails migrations every time I run the test suite (using in-memory sqlite database). How to turn off output from the migrations?

Example output

```
-- create_table("alerts", {:force=>true})
  -> 0.0038s
-- create_table("businesses", {:force=>true})
  -> 0.0061s
etc...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it by calling `ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = false`
Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L253

Comment: I put this in `/config/environments/test.rb` and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the ActiveRecord::Migration.supress_messages method like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.suppress_messages do
  # MIGRATION CODE
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on tilleryj's answer, you don't need to explicitly call `.suppress_messages` on the `ActiveRecord::Migration` class as migrations already inherit from this class (this is on the assumption that you are calling this method from within a migration). Therefore you can just call it like this:

```rb
suppress_messages do
  # MIGRATION CODE
end
```